# autohotkey: code read from INI

Tags: autohotkey, ini, flags, window-resize, remap

Hi all

The following code from here:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/1359 ... g-winmove/

it's for resize-a-window-using-winmove

**My question is**: Is it possible to divide the code into two files?

Part 1 into "*.ahk"

Part 2 into "*.ini"

I mean: Can the script read "Buttons" part of the code from the INI file?

If someone could show me how to do this, I would be very grateful!

; --------------------------------------------------------------part  1

```
#SingleInstance, Ignore
SetWorkingDir, D:\Re

Button_Names = Ec_1|Ec_2

Capslock::!F4
#q::
Gui, Destroy
Gui, -Caption +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop
Loop, 2
{
   I := A_Index
   Loop, Parse, Button_Names, |
      If(A_Index == I)
         Gui, Add, Button, % "x" 1 + (I-1) * 76 " y1 w75 h30 gButton" I, % A_LoopField
}
Gui, Show, Noactivate x15  y0 w1881 h32, MacroBar
Return

; --------------------------------------------------------------part  2
Button1:
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
RunWait, D:\font
RunWait, D:\Re
Sleep, 300
WinActivate, D:\Re
Sleep, 300
WinMove, Re,, 0, 40, 400, 600 
Sleep, 300
WinActivate, font
Sleep, 300
WinMove, D:\font,, 400, 40, 400, 600
return

Button2:
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
RunWait, D:\indesign
RunWait, D:\Re
Sleep, 200
WinActivate, D:\indesign
WinMove, D:\indesign,, 400, 40, 400, 600
Sleep, 200
WinActivate, Re
WinMove, Re,, 0, 40, 400, 600   

 ^!s::
ExitApp
```

Thaks

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is 'yes, you can' split the code into an INI and an AHK file.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm

So with a standard INI file looking like this: 
[SectionName]
Key=Value

You could try to give the buttons a section name, and each button a key/value combination.